# Grafana Geo Map Dashboard - Geo IP Configuration

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, geomap

I have installed Grafana in my AKS cluster and now I want to create a Dashboard which shows the Geo location of the users connecting. So I found the below dashboard in Grafana website.

```
https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/12559
```

But some of the panels shows "No Data" in this dashboard. For instance, Requests per Country doesn't show any data. The query used by this panel is

```
sum by (geoip_country_code) (count_over_time({$label_name=~"$label_value", job=~"$job", instance=~"$instance"} | json | geoip_country_code != "" | __error__="" [$__interval]))
```

[image]

I searched regarding this, and as far as I know, we need "Geo Map" plugin installed in our Grafana Dashboard. But I see the plugin installed in Grafana.

[image]

So in this case, do I need to install any kind of agent or something to gather metrics regarding location? I also see in the grafana dashboard saying below.

[image]

I can't understand where I should put this configuration. Is these parameters should be placed in the Config Map or else the NGINX Ingress Controller Annotation section?